# Syntax error on Dreamweaver when using boilerplate

Tags: jquery, html5boilerplate

I am a relatively new web site designer and I've used boilerplate about 4-5 times. It's great and I love all the problems it solves. Thanks for that!

However, every time I use it to create a page and then create a template from that page, Dreamweaver shows the following error:

"There is a syntax error on line (*line number*). Code hinting may not work until you fix this error."

No matter what site I've built, the error always directs me to the line with this code on it:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

It only shows the code when I create the template. Then it flags it in every page I create from that template.

First, I'm not that great with jQuery. Can someone please tell me what this code is saying?
Second, is there some way to keep the error from occurring?

Thanks in advance,
Katherine

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the nested `<script>` tags. Try this:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<scr'+'ipt src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"><\/scr'+'ipt>')</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dreamwever is too stupid to recognize nested SCRIPT tags. You may need to break them up so it doesn't see them.

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<sc'+'ript src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"><\/sc'+'ript>')</script>
```